# View inside a view

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, view

I would like to include a sub view with its own controller inside another view. The way I saw was to call `addSubview` in the code, but there's got to be a way to do all of this inside interface builder itself, without coding it up in the controller.

The subview I want to add is defined in it's own xib file.

Any pointers how to accomplish that, or if is at all possible?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1296903/143

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder from the Library drag a View (UIView) under you main Window.  Notice in my MainWindow.xib file the **View Mode** is a list so that it's easy to see the hierarchy and you can add more sub views as you need them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to create a brand new view. My question might have been a bit imprecise, but I'm trying to use a view that is defined in another xib file. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You would ordinarily use a view controller to load an external NIB from within interface builder. However, it does not seem to be possible to refer to this NIB's view once you've loaded it.

It does not seem to be possible to add the external view to a spot deeper in the hierarchy purely visually.

You could however create a class that would automatically load an external NIB during `-viewDidLoad:` and add it as its one and only child, hence simulating the effect. Then simply drag a UIView and change its class when dropped on the scene.